# How to fetch data from umlaut domain with curl?

Tags: curl, host

I try to fetch data from an umlaut domain via curl. Well, its not working, I get the error:

```
Could not resolve host: http://müller.de/ Host not found
```

following settings in Curl

```
    $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://müller.de/');             
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after trying a lot of things, the answer was really simpel. I have to work directly with the punycoded URL, just use the converter here:

https://iwantmyname.com/domain-tools/idns/idn-punycode-converter

I did not found anything on stackoverflow, so I shared my first Q&A style, hops this helps somebody :)